# Assign string to int in C

Tags: c, string, memory, printf, variable-assignment

I have this code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = "hello world";

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

why assigning a `string` to `int` variable not giving me a compilation error, but prints a garbage value.

**Edit 1:**

A lot of answers suggested to not ignore the warning. I wrote this code on ideone, which unfortunately, did not give me any warning.

Comment: `int i = "hello world";` here you assign `i` to the pointer on `"hello world"` string, it's not a garbage value. Strings in C are kinda pointers on it's first character.

Comment: If you did want to assign a string containing digits to an int then you could use atoi()

Comment: MSVC gives a warning: please treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: @fas - can you please give me some link to read about it? I understand that string literals are pointer on first char - but, `int i` is not a pointer type variable and if it is holding an address, the output should be a hexadecimal value? Am I wrong?

Comment: @prabodhprakash int holds just a number, and it would be printed in format you specified in printf, here you can read about possible formats http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/. Main problem here is in casting pointer to integer, C compilers doesn't treat this as an error, because pointer (address in memory) is a number too (but in most cases "address number" overflows int) and if you want, you can print pointer in any format you want: decimal, hexadecimal, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = "hello world";
```

With that you assigning the address of the string literal `"hello world"` in memory to the `int` object `i`, which is in most cases undefined behavior because the value of a memory location is in many cases beyond the area an object of type `int` can hold.

This undefined value is then printed by:

```
 printf("%d", i);
```

Nonetheless the compiler should give you a warning when doing that without an explicit cast, f.e. as I compiled your code by gcc it gave:

> warning: initialization of 'int' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Do never ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would perform a pointer to int conversion.  It should be a warning indicating the conversion without cast.